# onchange="javascript:updateModel()" What does the word 'javascript' do?

Tags: javascript, html

I often see html elements with an onchange attribute that specifies javascript as the language, e.g.:

```
onchange="javascript:updateModel()"
```

It still works if I remove *javascript:*

```
onchange="updateModel()"
```

Is it safe to remove it?
Are there some browsers (maybe older versions) that need it?

Comment: Nice one, @Ates. Goes on my list...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing. It shouldn't be there. It ends up being a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) on a statement, so it's valid, it's just pointless.

You use `javascript:`, the pseudo-protocol, in attributes where a URL is expected (such as `href`), not in attributes that are already designed to contain JavaScript code like `onclick`.

> Is it safe to remove it?

Yes.

> Are there some browsers (maybe older versions) that need it?

No. :-)